# How to split array or assign key , jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Using Jquery ,

I have an array result

```
[<a href=""><img src="image1"></a>,<a href=""><img src="image2"></a>]
```

if I try to do each I only get the first one in array ,

how could I split this so I could do

```
$.each(my_array, function (index, value) {
     this.parent().attr.('href',this.src);// assign image as href to parent
});
```

here is bad try

http://jsfiddle.net/ZZVXf/6/

Please note that array above is returned to my by imagesLoaded plugin for jquery and I canot select parent directly since it is not within the result , ZI must go by element.parent()
any help is appreciated. thnx!

Comment: yes thnx fixed but still same issue

Comment: @Baz1nga  [<a href=""><img src="image1"></a>,<a href=""><img src="image2"></a>]
  would be my array

Comment: That array is not valid JS syntax. Please show the code that creates the array, and the original source html. If you're trying to say that you have an array of references to DOM elements please say so more clearly (and, again, show your code).

Comment: `this` is the DOM reference, and you are trying to use `parent()` witch is a jQuery method, you need to wrap `this` with jQuery to access jQuery methods. and this will refer to the anchor tag, so you need to goto the image element first before trying to access its src path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following HTML:

`<a href=""><img src="image1"></a><a href=""><img src="image2"></a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`

And a jQuery selector which catches only these elements, in this case simply:

```
var my_array = $('a');
```

You would do:

```
$.each(my_array, function(i, el) {
    el.href = $(el).children('img').attr('src');
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wYzqE/)

---

If your selector is on the `img` tags:

```
var my_array = $('img');
```

You would do:

```
$.each(my_array, function(i, el) {
    $(el).parent().attr('href', el.src);
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wYzqE/1/)

Comment: I cant do that ,   this is being returned to me ,  is not like I am going trough markup and getting the values , all I can work with is  [<a href=""><img src="image1"></a>,<a href=""><img src="image2"></a>]

Comment: Yes you can, here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZVXf/7/   Be careful with your syntax.

Comment: If `my_array` is actually a jQuery object such as is returned by `$('img')` then you wouldn't use `$.each(my_array, function(i, el) {})` when you can say `my_array.each(function(i, el) {})`.

Answer (score 1):

Select the img elements.

```
var $imgs = $("a > img");
```

Loop over selected elements

```
$imgs.each(function () {
    $(this).parent().attr('href',this.src);// assign image as href to parent
});
```

Note there is no '.' after attr, since that is a method. Also, you need to do `$(this)`, since `this` in the loop is a dom element, not a jquery object.

Comment: that is exactly what we tried , see fiddle please, this is log Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'parent'   from your code and my array , note that I am getting this returned trough imagesLoaded jquery plugin  .

Comment: @Benn - this answer is _not_ the same as your fiddle, this corrects the problems in your fiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZVXf/8/

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `$imgs` is; it's a reference to the jquery object which matches the selector -- a reference to the and the `.each` method on a jquery object loops through matched elements and passes them into the loop as `this`. Doing $(this) gives you a jquery reference to the object, so you can't _possibly_ see an issue of image element not having method parent, like you had originally with only `this`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ['<a href=""><img src="image1"></a>','<a href=""><img src="image2"></a>'];

$.each(arr, function (index, value) {
    alert(value.replace(/^.*src="(.*)".*$/m, '$1'));
});
```

Comment: thnx for tying but why use regex when this should be a normal foreach?  here is fiddle , is strange http://jsfiddle.net/ZZVXf/6/

Comment: @Benn i've not understend your question, sorry. I think that you have an array and you want to search src value and put it in some href. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
var obj = ['<a href=""><img src="image1"></a>,<a href=""><img src="image2"></a>']

jQuery(obj).each(function(key,value){
    var imgObj = jQuery(value).find('img')
       jQuery(imgObj ).each(function(key,value){ 
            jQuery(this).parent('a').attr('href',jQuery(this).attr('src')); 
     });
});​
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sLYDV/)

Answer (score 0):

if your code is: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZVXf/6/ then you just need to change it to:

```
$.each($('img'), function (index, value) {
    $(this).parent().attr('href', this.src);// assign image as href to parent
});
```

because you want to access the jQuery methods you need to wrap this with jQuery (witch is the DOM reference, not a jQuery reference).